# When documenting a with \code{\link[package], avoid a link to nowhere in the pdf

Tags: r, pdf, r-markdown, roxygen

When I write function documentation in R and I reference an external package I use  `\code{\link[package]{function}}` and that works great for the `?` function in interactive R.

But then my pdf files have linked text for "function" and the link just goes to my table of contents. How can I turn off these links for the pdf?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can take advantage of the [conditional text](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-devel/R-exts.html#Conditional-text) macros in the Rd format. The example given in Writing R Extensions is a quite simple demonstration of HTML versus LaTeX format:

```
\if{latex}{\out{\alpha}}\ifelse{html}{\out{&alpha;}}{alpha}
```

The conditionality can be expressed in an if-then (`\if{format}{alternate}`) or if-then-else (`\ifelse{format}{text}{alternate}`) structure. So, for your example, you might do something like:

```
\if{html}{\code{\link[package]{function}}}
```

or:

```
\ifelse{html}{\code{\link[package]{function}}}{\code{function}}
```

Note: You can also express multiple formats as a comma-separated list such as `\ifelse{latex,html}{...}{...}`.

Comment: This seems more like a bug in the Rd to pdf system to me

Comment: @hadley perhaps, though that is the only behavior I have ever observed in PDF docs.

Comment: Just to be clear, in my case I wanted  

`\ifelse{latex}{\code{function}}{\code{\link[package]{function}}}`

Comment: @hadley It is apparently intended behavior: https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/trunk/src/library/tools/R/Rd2latex.R#L228-L234, https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-devel/R-exts.html#DOCF78

Comment: Still seems like a bug to me